# Method for Sampling High Dimensionality Simulation (similar to Latin Hypercube Sampling)

Tags: sampling, expected-value, monte-carlo, latin-hypercube

I need to calculate the expected outputs (Yj) from a large non-linear simulation model (Mj) which takes 2^N possible input strings (Bi), each with known probability fi (simple binomial). N is typically 12 or more, e.g.,

Yj = E(Mj(Bi))

where Bi are

000000000000,
000000000001,
000000000010,
...,
111111111111

The calculation of Mj is very expensive so I want a way to subsample the Bi to get an accurate estimate of the expected value of Mj without having to calculate it exhaustively (something in the spirit of Latin Hypercube Sampling or Gaussian Quadrature). Any ideas?

Comment: Actually it's not quite that simple, as the elements of Bi are Poisson rather than 0/1.

Comment: Maybe it's basically a high-dimensional integral (summation), which suggests Monte Carlo methods. But I'd prefer a non-stochastic method.

Comment: I think Simon you fully got the point: It is a high dimensional problem. All I know and tested so far shows that in such situation random MC is hard to beat. Most methods fail if the number of dimensions goes beyond 10 or so. Have you tried to strip down the problem to say N=3, and found a solution? What is the limitation of it for large N? I think the curse of dimensionality is almost impoassible to beat. Can you exploit any special characteristic of your problem? Like about known probability fi?

Comment: Thanks. I solved the problem by constructing a piecewise linear approximation to the cumulative probability distribution and tracking its evolution through each time step N. It turns out to be very stable.